# How to end external Interrupt Service Routine (ISR) in 8051

Tags: c, embedded, 8051

I wrote a simple led blinking code with hardware interrupt 0 of 8051.
When button is pressed it goes into interrupt service routine (ISR). After executing it should come back in main function but it is not coming.
This is my c code. Any positive reply will be appreciated.

```
sbit LED = P1^0;

void delay(int ms)
{ 
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<ms;i++)
   {
     TMOD = 0x01;             
     TH0 = 0xFC;             
     TL0 = 0x66;
     TR0 = 1; 
     while(TF0==0);                                     
     TR0 = 0;
     TF0 = 0;
   }
}



void main(void)
{
    P1 = 0x00;
/// P3 = 0x04;
    IT0 = 1;     
    EX0 = 1;      
    EA  = 1; 
    LED=1;

    while(1)
    {   
      LED=~LED;
      delay(200);
    }

 return ;
}



void external0_isr() interrupt 0     
{ 
   EA=0;
   LED =0 ;
   delay(2000);
   LED=1;
   EX0=1;
   EA=1;

   return;
}
```

Comment: In general, you want to spend as little time as possible in an ISR. The `delay(2000)` seems out of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter the button interrupt, you disable global interrupt `EA=0;`
That also disables the timer interrupt. Therefore, you program would hang at `while(TF0==0)` in your  `delay(2000)` routine.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. Itried it by commenting  EA=0  but it  doesn't work.

Comment: The reason EA=0 there is to prevent multiple IO interrupt by bouncing button. Normally, even if you only press 1 times, the MCU may receive 3-5 interrupt signal if you dont have any noise filtering capacitors. Besides, you should avoid nested interrupt (interrupt inside interrupt) in your design. And finally, dont use delay in interrupt. Interrupt should be as fast as possible.

Comment: To make sure that interrupt is not the reason of fault, please change your `delay` function by using `for loop` instead of system timer. http://blowtech.blogspot.com/2013/08/different-ways-to-generate-delays-in.html

Comment: Thank you  dear ,       Its working  with  for loop delay .

Comment: How I can use timers delay in interrupt  any suggestions.please

Comment: You should not do that. You can set a global variable X inside your IO interrupt. Then in your main while, you can check whether the X is set to handle your delay.   `while(1) { if (X=1) delay(2000); else delay(200); }`

Comment: Thanks   its working   by setting  flag   TF0=1  in  ISR.